# How to make a Windows service start before another at Windows startup

Tags: windows, windows-service, startup

Is it possible to make a Windows service (third-party one, I don't control its code) to start only after a service I own?

I need that to connect to a device which is blocked by the third-party service.

Comment: See the duplicate question; adding a dependency to the service should do exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:
Look at the properties of the services to get the service names (not the display names. In the example below I have used the Smart Card Service, the service name is scardsvr

Then from an administrative command prompt use the command:
sc config scardsvr start= auto depend= "netlogon"
[image]